# Functions are not valid as a React child error gets throw when Provider is wrapped

Tags: react-redux, material-ui

I'm unable to figure out why I'm getting this error in the console. (I have tried putting the Redux Provider inside MuiTheme, but it doesn't seem to work)

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <CssBaseline/>
            <App />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    </Provider>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```